# JPA MappedSuperclass with ManyToOne

Tags: jpa, entity, mappedsuperclass

I'm facing kind of typical issue. Imagine typical 1-N relationship between objects. To be precise User(U) and Room(R): [U]*---1[R].

Here comes the problem, Room should be abstract base class with implementations for example BlueRoom, RedRoom. How correctly set relationship within User entity?

```
public interface Room { ... }
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class RoomSuperclass implements Room { ... }
@Entity
public class BlueRoom extends RoomSuperclass { ... }
@Entity
public class RedRoom extends RoomSuperclass { ... }


@Entity
public class User {

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ???) // I don't know if it will be BlueRoom or RedRoom
  private Room room; // ManyToOne cannot be applied on mapped superclass
}
```

I know this could be probably solved by using @Entity on RoomSuperclass instead of @MappedSuperclass but I'm not sure if it is good solution and if there is any better one.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. If you have an association to something, then this something must be an entity.

Comment: Thanks for a reply JB, I will wait day, two if someone else replies and then close the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@MappedSuperclass is not an @entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991236/mappedsuperclass-is-not-an-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to commentaries under the post. Declaring superclass as @Entity is the solution.

Comment: Could you explain for what purpose there's @MappedSuperclass ?

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same damn thing. I'm banging my head against the wall for half a day trying to use this annot because I don't want to map my abstract entity into a Table !!!! It's ABSTRACT ! but no, if I want to use inheritance, I have to specify a mapped entity, so what is this annot made for ??

Comment: **An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass**.

Answer (score 1):

A super class annotated with the `MappedSuperclass` should not be annotated with `Entity`.

Relation annotations can only be used with a class annotated with `Entity`.

You can replace the `MappedSuperclass` annotation with `Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` and add the `Entity` annotation to your super class.

This way hibernate will create a database table for each class. there is other strategies that you can check out in [the official docs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/inheritancetype).

> JOINED
> A strategy in which fields that are specific to a subclass are mapped to a separate table than the fields that are common to the parent class, and a join is performed to instantiate the subclass.

> SINGLE_TABLE
> A single table per class hierarchy.

> TABLE_PER_CLASS
> A table per concrete entity class.