# @MappedSuperclass is not an @Entity in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, orm

So I am using DerbyDB and I am setting up some entities. I have a `@MappedSuperclass` which is used as a superclass for some entities (`@Entity`). More specifically, I have a superclass `User` and 3 subclasses namely `admin`, `regular` and `guest`. Now I have a different entity, let's say `file` that should reference (as one of its fields) its owner. So I created a field called `User owner`.
The error I get is:

```
Exception Description: [File] uses a non-entity [User] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field owner].
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Your error is clearly specific to whichever JPA implementation you use (and you dont tell us which one). My JPA provider allows use of MappedSuperclass in relations.

Comment: @NeilStockton, what JPA-provider allows the use of MappedSuperclass as an entity? as of oracle documentation: "Mapped superclasses cannot be queried and cannot be used in EntityManager or Query operations."

Comment: DataNucleus JPA does IIRC, and any JPA vendor can offer their own extensions to the (limited) JPA specification (like others do in other areas).

Comment: @NeilStockton thx for info, I only worked with EclipseLink and Hibernate so far, which don't allow a MappedSuperclass to be an entity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can suggest two solutions:

### Change Inheritance

The exception you get clearly describes your problem: `User` is not an entity. Any class declared as superclass with the interface `@MappedSuperclass` cannot be an entity *(in standard JPA - depends on your JPA-provider)*... let me point you to an answer I just gave to quite a similar problem

--> [Superclass-Types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894347/5909679)

So defining your superclass as an abstract entity will give you the desired behaviour, you described.

#### Extra:

If you choose your inheritance mapping strategy as `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` you don't even need multiple database-tables. Here is a good example: [JPA Single-Table Inheritance](https://web.archive.org/web/20200628171124/http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/)

### Change Model (suggested)

Don't split your user entity in several entities just by their roles. Make an `Enum` with all your desired roles and add it as a field to your `User`-entity. This is widely more common, unless u need your admin, guests etc to be an own object...

Comment: I thought of that but can't really change model as each user has it's own attributes. Only a few basic stuff applies to all user-types

Comment: Ok, i see. If there are a lot of different extra attributes I advice to use InheritanceType.JOINED. SINGLE_TABLE otherwise will result in a lot of redundant data (empty columns)... happy coding =)

Answer (score 23):

`@MappedSupperclass` is different than the `@Inheritance` annotation.

`@MappedSuperclass` tells the JPA provider to include the base class persistent properties as if they were declared by the child class extending the superclass annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`.

However, the inheritance is only visible in the OOP world, since, from a database perspective, there's no indication of the base class. Only the child class entity will have an associated mapped table.

The `@Inheritance` annotation is meant to materialize the OOP inheritance model in the database table structure. More, you can query a base class annotated with `@Inheritance` but you can't do that for a base class annotated with [`@MappedSuperclass`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes to inherit child class we create a parent class but we don't use it as a table.Inheriting that parent class we create various table.That's why we don't use @Entity in a parent class. Rather than we use @MappedSuperClass in a parent or super class.