# How to have a common generic repository for Springboot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my models:-

```
    @MappedSuperclass
public class IdCommon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant created;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant updated;

}



    @Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEES")
public class EmployeeEntity extends IdCommon {
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, length=200)
    private String email;
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeEntity [id=" + 0 + ", firstName=" + firstName +
                ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email   + "]";
    }
}
```

My repository and service:-

```
@Repository
public interface CommonRepository<E extends IdCommon> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {

  }

 @Service
 public class EmployeeService {

//@Autowired
EmployeeRepository repository;

//@Autowired
CommonRepository<EmployeeEntity> commonRepository;

@Autowired
public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository repository, CommonRepository<EmployeeEntity> commonRepository) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.commonRepository = commonRepository;
}

public Page<EmployeeEntity> getAll(Pageable pageable){
    Specification<EmployeeEntity> specification = (Specification<EmployeeEntity>) (root, query, builder) -> null;
    return commonRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
}
}
```

Controller:-

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController2 {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")

    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "integer", paramType = "query",
                    value = "page number"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "integer", paramType = "query",
                    value = "Number of records per page."),
    })
    public Page<EmployeeEntity> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = "created") String sortBy,
                                       @ApiIgnore Pageable pageable,
                                       @ApiParam(value = "sortDirection (desc/asc)")
                                       @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false, defaultValue = "asc") String sortDirection){
        if (sortDirection.equals("desc")) {
            pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(sortBy).descending());
        } else {
            pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(sortBy).ascending());
        }
        return employeeService.getAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

I got this error:-

> : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with
> path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
> is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an
> entity: class com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.IdCommon; nested exception
> is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class
> com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.IdCommon] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class
> com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.IdCommon

As the above error says it is not en entity. So I added the @Entity annotation to IdCommon. Then I got new error:-

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with
> both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass:
> com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.IdCommon

how do I achieve this? My requirements is have generic repository type. I will have many similar entity. To avoid many code, I should use generics.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991236/mappedsuperclass-is-not-an-entity-in-jpa

Answer (score 1):

It has been sometime now, I hope you have got your solution already. But, for others who face the same issue I will try to reason out why your solution is not working.

The first thing is that your repository has to be annotated with `@NoRepositoryBean` like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepository<E extends IdCommon> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {}
```

And which will be exteded in `EmployeeRepository`:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CommonRepository<EmployeeEntity> {
    //you can override some or all of the methods if necessary
}
```

Service class is more or less the same:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    private EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.empRepository = repository;
    }

    public void saveEmployee(EmployeeEntity entity) {//I added this for a test
        empRepository.save(entity);
    }
    
    public Page<EmployeeEntity> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<EmployeeEntity> specification = (Specification<EmployeeEntity>) (root, query, builder) -> null;
        return empRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
    }
}
```

And running this with `CommandLineRunner` (lazy to add a controller)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
        entity.setEmail("aa@so.com");
        entity.setFirstName("First name");
        entity.setLastName("Last name");
        
        service.saveEmployee(entity);
        
        Page<EmployeeEntity> page = service.getAll(PageRequest.of(0, 1));
        page.getContent().stream().forEach(System.out::println); //output: EmployeeEntity [id=0, firstName=First name, lastName=Last name, email=aa@so.com]
    }

}
```

Comment: I got this error: 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.service.RevisionService required a bean of type 'com.test.service.RevisionRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.service.RevisionRepository' in your configuration.

I followed almost same config as ur example.

Comment: the problem seems package scanning issue, check well that you are scanning all necessary packages. in your case, atleast`com.test.service` has to be scanned

Comment: Looks like if I change @ NoRepositoryBean to @ Repository then it can start the app. But it doesn't work fulfills my reequipments.

Comment: Did you try to scan all the packages?

Comment: In the same package I have other repository and those are working fine except this new one with  @ NoRepositoryBean. So scan is not the issue here. As said that if I change to @ Repository then it starts and but eventually it doesn't serve my reequipments.

Comment: The class with `@NoRepositoryBean` is not supposed to be injected as a repositoy, adding `@Repository` is waste of time. May be the problem is something else, I will try to put my example on github and let you know.

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/amenski/mapped-super-class.git

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation for some time. I will defiantly check this. Thanks in advance!